# Retrieving data from db to datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Public Class StudDetails

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim sdp As SqlDataAdapter 'help get data from db connect datagridview with database table'
    Dim ds As DataSet  
    Dim dtable As DataTable 
    Dim query As String
    Dim COMMAND As SqlCommand

     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Button1.Click

        con = New SqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-6RSFF1M;Initial Catalog=StudNew ;Integrated Security=True"
        Dim bsource As New BindingSource
        Try
            con.Open()
            query = "SELECT EnrollmentNo,Name,[Subject Name1],[Out Of1],          [Marks Obtained1] from StudNew.Sem1M1 where EnrollmentNo = '" & TextBox1.Text   & "' "
            COMMAND = New SqlCommand(query, con)
            sdp.SelectCommand = COMMAND
            sdp.Fill(dtable)
            bsource.DataSource = dtable
            DataGridView2.DataSource = bsource
            sdp.Update(dtable)
            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is mycode to retrieve data from database named StudNew and table named Sem1M1.I have also binded the datagridview with my database and connected my form to database. Dont know why the data isnt showing up in the gridview.

Comment: First of all, you have an empty `Catch` block so, for all you know, an exception is being thrown.  Maybe you should provide some sort of feedback if an exception is thrown, while debugging at least.

Comment: There is no exception during execution nor any error but when i click on the button after running it its not working.

Comment: Secondly, what is that `Update` call there for? `Update` is for saving changes but what changes are there going to be when you only just retrieved the data?

Comment: As for the issue, what value does `Fill` return?  If that's zero then it means that there's no data that matches your query, so seeing no data is what you should expect.  If it's not zero then that's another matter.

Comment: ya that i can remove but still not working. i got many errors b4 this as i did without binding the db but even this simple code is unable to produce o/p on my machine

Comment: so what should be done with the fill command?

Comment: What should be done with the `Fill` method is it should be called, you get the return value and then tell us what it is.